# MySQL php query appears to be returning wrong result (probably obvious)

Tags: php, mysqli

MySql Appears to be returning the wrong result and I do not know why (new to mysql so its probably obvious but I couldn't find the answer)

home.php:

```
    $testUID = query("SELECT `uid` FROM `userid` WHERE `session_id` = '".$_COOKIE['phpAuth']."'",$link);
            echo $testUID;
```

echoes "1" when `$_COOKIE['phpAuth']` is "ABCD"

But the MySQL `userid` table looks like this (test values obviously) so surely it should return 0?

```
    name  | pass     | csrf | uid  | session_id
    -------------------------------------------
    admin | password | ABCD | 0    | ABCD
```

Sorry I forgot completely that query() was my own function and 
(`$link` is the connection the the database)

```
function query($request,$link) {
    return mysqli_query($link,$request)or die(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

EDIT:

Simplified,

```
echo mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query(mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb"),"SELECT `uid` FROM `userid` WHERE `session_id` = 'ABCD'"))['uid'];
```

works perfectly but is in no way different to the current process as far as I can see so I'm even more confused.

```
echo mysqli_fetch_assoc($testuid)['uid'];
```

doesn't work with error

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, 
boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Home.php on line 37
```

Comment: `$testUID` is most likely a result.  You need to `fetch` or whatever the function from your API is.

Comment: I'd rather say that `query()` returns the execution success (true/false). Resources would not print as a number and objects usually give an error when printed as is.

Comment: your code failed, outright. You're using a mysqli_ api to connect with, but using a mysql_ method to query with, being the connection's at the end.

Comment: `echo mysqli_fetch_assoc($testUID)['uid'];`

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I am using mysqli_query and mysqli_connect so why would that cause any issue?

Comment: `,$link` that isn't needed; it's mysql_ syntax for the connection at the end.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The procedural style of [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) _does_ take the connection identifier as the first argument.

Comment: @PatrickQ you're missing something; look at `$_COOKIE['phpAuth']."'",$link);` << that.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks I thought I was going mad for a minute

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Right, but that's the call to OP's custom `query()` function which wraps (and, for some reason, swaps the argument order of) `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_query() returns something that is NOT an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346183/mysqli-query-returns-something-that-is-not-an-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested, changing

```
function query($request,$link) {
    return mysqli_query($link,$request)or die(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

to

```
function query($request,$link) {
    return mysqli_query($link,$request);// or die(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

resolves the error completely

Comment: Ahhhh...okay, I see now.  It's an order of operations quirk.  The `or` converts everything after the `return` into a boolean evaluation.  The first part of it (the `mysqli_query()` call) produces a truthy value, meaning the whole thing is true, and then true (represented by "1") is returned.

Comment: @PatrickQ Ah of course, query() updated accordingly and now works perfectly: 
  
`$result = mysqli_query($link,$request) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    return $result;

}`